# IOS app's back button causing closing the webview(of react app) and back to the app

Tags: ios, swift, webview, wkwebview

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

```
if (webview.canGoBack()) {
    webview.goBack();
} else {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

}`